# Pam module debug creates duplicate log messages

Tags: password, pam

I have a test server that i recently implement `debug` module argument in pam.d/common-password config file.

And it does produce info log entries that i am looking for. But one weird issue is that creates duplicate same log entry even with same pid. Not sure why

See example:

```
Jun 23 23:12:55 testserver1 passwd[3067]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): username [root] obtained
Jun 23 23:12:55 testserver1 passwd[3067]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): username [root] obtained
Jun 23 23:12:57 testserver1 passwd[3067]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password - new password not obtained
```

Now i do want the passwd{ prefix pam module logs. But weird thing , why username was obtained messages duplicate twice ?

I have check the only debug argument flag in pam.d directory is in common-password. WOuld like some assistance. thanks

Comment: There is not enoth info to reproduce the problem things that you should edit in are whet type of server etc.

Comment: and welcome to ask ubuntu